# Which .NET data type is best for mapping the NUMBER Oracle data type in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, oracle10g, nhibernate-mapping

I've seen some examples in which `decimal` is used in NHibernate projects for mapping to whole number columns in Oracle. Right now I'm using `int` and `long` in my program.

What are the advantages of `decimal` over `int`/`long`? Does it perform better?

Comment: What do you mean by "What are the advantages of decimal over int/long? Does it perform better?", decimals are not whole numbers like int/long...

Comment: @Phill However, a decimal **can** represent a whole number, and I've seen `decimal` used instead of `int`/`long` in various examples. I'm just trying to understand why.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

> I've seen decimal used instead of int/long in various examples. I'm just trying to understand why

That's probably because .NET `decimal` and Oracle `NUMBER` [maps a bit better](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk72thhd.aspx) than `long` and `NUMBER` and it also gives you more flexibility. If you at a later stage add a *scale* in the Oracle column then you wouldn't have to change datatype if you already used `decimal`.

`decimal` is certainly slower than `int` and `long` since the later two are supported in hardware. That said, you have to crunch some serious amount of data for it to make any difference. I still think that you should use `long` if that that's what you're dealing with and then you should also let the table column definitions represent that. `NUMBER(18,0)` for `long` and so on.

The reason `decimal` maps a little better is that `long` is 64 bits and `decimal` is (kind of) 128 bits.

**.NET**

> > Type: **decimal**
> >     Approximate Range: ±1.0 × 10^−28 to ±7.9 × 10^28
> >     Precision: 28-29 significant digits
> >
> > Type: **long**
> >     Range: –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
> >     Precision: 18 (19 for ulong) significant digits

**Oracle**

`NUMBER` [defaults](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#g23242) to 38 significant digits and scale 0 (integer).

> > Type: **NUMBER**
> >     Range: +- 1 x 10^-130 to 9.99...9 x 10^125
> >     Precision: 38 significant digits

Microsoft is aware of the problem and [notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk72thhd.aspx)

> This data type is an alias for the
>   NUMBER(38) data type, and is designed
>   so that the OracleDataReader returns a
>   System.Decimal or OracleNumber instead
>   of an integer value. Using the .NET
>   Framework data type can cause an
>   overflow.

Come to think of it you actually need [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) to be able to represent the same number of significant digits as to what `NUMBER` defaults to. I've never seen anyone do that and I would suppose it's a very rare need. Also `BigInteger` still wouldn't cut it since `NUMBER` can be of positive and negative infinity.

Comment: Learn something new every day :)

Comment: //This makes lot more sense to me. Thanks a lot Jonas for this great explanation...!

Comment: In pinch, you can always use map to `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleDecimal` as hinted in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/featTypes.htm - IIRC works with Number(38) and handles +/-INF cases.

Answer (score 49):

```
[.NET: Int32] = [Oracle:NUMBER(2)..NUMBER(9)*] 
[.NET: Int64] = [Oracle:NUMBER(10)..NUMBER(18)*]
[.NET: Double] = [Oracle:NUMBER(x, 0)..NUMBER(x, 15)*]
[.NET: Double] = [Oracle: FLOAT]
[.NET: Decimal] = [Oracle:NUMBER]
```

Comment: I don't know where you took this from, but this is not what happens de facto. From what I see, `double` is mapped to `DOUBLE PRECISION`, `int` is always mapped to `NUMBER(10,0)` and `decimal` can be mapped to any `NUMBER(x,y)` depending on the `.Precision(x).Scale(y)` settings. By the way, chaning the `.Precision` of `int` doesn't change the mapping - it's still `NUMBER(10,0)`. And besides, this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I use `Devart`, I read the following answer which describe the CSDL mapping types between Oracle and .Net .http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=15604

Comment: It depends on the way you lock at the Problem:
If you want to store an `int32` `(max = 2,147,483,647)` you need a `NUMBER(10,0)`.
If you want to read a `NUMBER(10,0)` `(max = 9,999,999,999)` you need a `long`. Since the boundaries follow completely different concepts, there is no way around that. You have to know where the data comes from and maybe use additional db constraints.

Answer (score 17):

```
NUMBER(1,0)     => Boolean          
NUMBER(5,0)     => Int16/short.MaxValue == 32767    
NUMBER(10,0)    => Int32/int.MaxValue == 2,147,483,647    
NUMBER(19,0)    => Int64/long.MaxValue == 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

Comment: It's safer to map an int32 to NUMBER(9,0) if you want to ensure that all values stored in Oracle can fit into an int32, and safer to map int64 to NUMBER(18,0) for the same reason.

From the opposite direction, ensuring that Oracle will accept all values that start from C#, the original numbers are best.