# Oracle sql setting integer

Tags: c#, sql

I set my table column as integer.
Now I am trying to read it in my c# code using getint32 and for some reason I get a cast error, and when I checked some more I saw that I am getting a decimal from my db. how can that be? Isn't the oracle integer equals to c# int?

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(@"select id,title from table"))
{
    cmd.Connection = _conn;
    OracleDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (r.Read())
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(reader.GetFieldType(0)); // <--decimal
        //reader.GetDecimal(0);
        reader.GetInt32(0); <---cast error
        Debugger.Break();
    }
    r.Close();
 }
```

the id column is set as integer, also tryed number. comfused :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read at this:

[Which .NET data type is best for mapping the NUMBER Oracle data type in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502016/which-net-data-type-is-best-for-mapping-the-number-oracle-data-type-in-nhiberna)

Oracle number maps to .net decimal. Microsoft is aware of this issue.

Comment: finnaly my answer , ty.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do that.

An `int` (`System.Int32`) is not big enough to hold every possible `decimal` value. If your column type is `decimal`, use [`GetDecimal()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdecimal.aspx) method, if your column type is `int`, use [`GetInt32()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32.aspx) method.

There is no implicitly conversation `decimal` to `int` at all.

Comment: but as i said , my column type is integer, thats my all problem

Comment: But in your code you say `reader.GetFieldType(0)` procude `decimal`?

Comment: that the all question, why am i getting decimal when in oracle db i set the column as integer/number. please read what i wrote..