# How to generate 38 digit ID mapping in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Just to clarify this *entity framework* specific question isn't a duplicate of the suggested NHibernate question and doesn't deal only with .Net number types but also EF Mapping

---

EDIT

so to restate the question more succinctly:

### How do you configure EF6 to use a type capable of 38 significant digits as an Id?

I have to import data **into MS-SQL** that has been exported from an Oracle database. The ID column in that database is defined as NUMBER(38). Some of the ID values are negative.

While I'm not expecting we'll store that many rows of data (crikey!) I'm not certain how best to model this.

Thinking first of how to represent this in my POCOS and looking at MSDN I can see that [integral types don't give enough digits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [neither do floating point values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ahet949%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Using [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) as my Id fields would allow for arbitrarily large values but my google-fu doesn't find an obvious link from BigInteger through EF to a SQL data type.

I'm guessing I can declare my Ids as `BigInteger` in code and in the mapping use `HasColumnType` to set the DB column to NUMERIC and set `HasPrecision(38, 0)`

Can anyone say if that suggestion would work or if not how to actually solve this?

---

**UPDATE**

So, I've ran some tests this morning.

EF 6 contains the ability to set catch-all configuration for type configurations so...

```
    modelBuilder.Properties<BigInteger>().Configure(config => config.HasPrecision(38, 0));
    modelBuilder.Properties<BigInteger>().Configure(config => config.HasColumnType("Numeric"));
```

However, if I try to run that I get the error:

> The type 'System.Numerics.BigInteger' cannot be used to filter
>   properties. Only scalar types, string, and byte[] are supported.

So either I have to set BigInteger to Numeric config elsewhere or try something else

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which .NET data type is best for mapping the NUMBER Oracle data type in NHibernate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502016/which-net-data-type-is-best-for-mapping-the-number-oracle-data-type-in-nhiberna)

Comment: According to this likely duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502016/which-net-data-type-is-best-for-mapping-the-number-oracle-data-type-in-nhiberna the answer is "if you actually have 38-digit numbers in your DB this is going to be really hard." because the oracle data providers aren't gonna cooperate either...

Comment: Ah ha - that is a similar issue except I'm not using Oracle and I'm not using NHibernate :-) I almost linked that question in mine. Here I'm looking specifically for both a .Net type and a the entity framework mapping code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was in the error message:

> Only scalar types, string, and byte[] are supported.

The largest scalar type available is decimal. [Which "only" allows 28-29 significant digits.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx)

So what I was attempting is impossible with Entity Framework

---

The entity framework team has subsequently confirmed this on Twitter

Answer (score 0):

Could you convert the ID to a Guid during the import?

```
    BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(int.MaxValue);
    Guid guid = new Guid(bigInteger.ToByteArray());
```

Comment: possibly. I could store it as a string. It's an external ID so I need to be able to reference it directly. It's also used to generate object relationships so ideally I want to use it directly as it can then simply be a foreign key.

Comment: I assume that an external ID is an ID that is generated in another system that you want to reference. I would suggest mapping that to your own internal id (guid, int, long, whatever) for the purposes of generating object relationships. Then you can keep that grief isolated to just one table.

Comment: That's definitely one mechanism we're considering. But it isn't just one table :-( The entire DB structure including relationships is being passed on to us. So if I can pull it in without having to do too much processing that'd be awesome... Thanks