# Oracle datatype to C# types

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to convert Oracle data types to C# equivalents.
I execute queries something similar to this.

```
Select CAST ((CASE WHEN RateType = 1 THEN 2
                   WHEN RateType = 2 THEN 6
                   ELSE 18
             END) AS NUMBER(10))
FROM SomeTable
```

There are case statements in that but ultimately my outermost statement is casting it to Number(10)

Then I use OracleDataReader.GetSchemaTable to determine type of the column in my C# code. I am getting System.Decimal with precision 38 and scale 127.
I was expecting an System.Integer with precision 10 and scale 0. Is this as  expected result or do i need to something different to determine column type?

Comment: Isnt this a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502016/which-net-data-type-is-best-for-mapping-the-number-oracle-data-type-in-nhiberna ?

Comment: Integers do not have precision. Oracle's INTEGER is essentially an alias for the decimal type NUMBER with precision 38 and scale 0. The correct mapping for decimal types is System.Decimal

Comment: I don't think that is duplicate for that one. However, If you can probably explain more on how it applies to this scenario, I can mark my as duplicate

Comment: I guess even if I get System.Decimal using OracleDataReader.GetSchemaTable. The precision should still be 10 and scale 0. Why is it (38,127)

Comment: Are you looking for this: [C#: Oracle Data Type Equivalence with OracleDbType](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583150/c-oracle-data-type-equivalence-with-oracledbtype#1583197)