# Oracle ORA-06502 PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I know there is a lot of these things, and I've gone through basically all of them, and I can't seem to find an answer to my problem.

I have a package with a function as follows:

```
FUNCTION AFunction(AString1 varchar2, ANumber NUMBER, AString2 VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
```

In `C#` I execute it like

```
using (var cmd = new OracleCommand("SCHEMA.MYPACKAGE.AFunction", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("AString1", "Param1");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("ANumber", 123);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("AString2", "Param2");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("ReturnValue", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Additional information: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 1

In Debug I can see that `Param1`, `Param2` and `ReturnValue` is `varchar2` and `ANumber` is Int32. Even if I change ANumber to Int64, it still does not work, and I'm not sure why I get this error, because everything seem fine. Can anybody maybe point out to me if I made a silly mistake?

If I execute this in toad it works without a problem.

```
DECLARE 
  RetVal VARCHAR2(200);
  PARAM1 VARCHAR2(4000);
  PARAM2 VARCHAR2(100);
  ANUMBER NUMBER;

BEGIN 
  PARAM1 := 'AParam1';
  ANUMBER := 123;
  PARAM2 := 'AParam2';

  RetVal := SCHEMA.MYPACKAGE.AFunction ( PARAM1, ANUMBER, PARAM2 );
  COMMIT; 
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling a function, the return parameter must be the first parameter in the collection, so

```
using (var cmd = new OracleCommand("SCHEMA.MYPACKAGE.AFunction", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("ReturnValue", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("AString1", "Param1");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("ANumber", 123);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("AString2", "Param2");

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: My word. This is almost too good to be true. Different error now, but it is because of sizes for the varchar2's I'm sure

Comment: Needed to specify size on ReturnValue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, the out/return parameters must be of appropriate sizes to support all returned values.

Comment: Just for others out there, order matters on the rest of the parameters also unless you set command.BindByName=true; then it goes by param name. My guess is there is some overhead to this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `decimal` instead of `int`; see [Which .NET data type is best for mapping the NUMBER Oracle data type in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502016/which-net-data-type-is-best-for-mapping-the-number-oracle-data-type-in-nhiberna).

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("ANumber", 123m);
```

Comment: I've tried that as well. I'm going to try this ReturnValue first approach quickly