# .NET Int16 limits less than NUMBER(5, 0) limits in Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-core

According to [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/entityCodeFirst.htm#ODPNT8310), Oracle suggest mapping a `NUMBER(5, 0)` column to `Int16`. However I realized that `Int16` has a range of `-32,768 to +32,767` but `NUMBER(5, 0)` has a range of `-99999 to 99999`. So is it really best practice to use `Int16` in this scenario?

I understand that if all my data flows into the database through my .NET code, then I am effectively limiting the column to an `Int16` and there should be no problems, but what if there is another application that inserts a value of `99999` into this column, which I then read and breaks my application because it doesn't fit to `Int16`? I'm just looking for best practices / suggestions, thanks.

I have already looked at [Which .NET data type is best for mapping the NUMBER Oracle data type in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502016/which-net-data-type-is-best-for-mapping-the-number-oracle-data-type-in-nhiberna), which is in regards to a whole `NUMBER` datatype but I'm asking regarding a `NUMBER(5, 0)` datatype.

Comment: If the data originates in a C# program that uses Int16 (aka `short`), then `Number(5,0)` will be able to hold any possible value.  If you are accessing arbitrary `Number(5,0)` data in the database from a C# program, then you are better off using `int` (aka Int32).

Comment: @Flydog57 right, but if I use `int` then it would be possible for a user to insert a value larger than `Number(5, 0)` can hold. Do you know how I could handle that?

Comment: Validate it before doing the insert.

Comment: @Amy Ok good enough, thanks!

Comment: @amy - a check constraint on the database table is a safer option

Comment: If you have many columns like this with many check constraints, updates and inserts will be slower. Point #2 - nobody should run code directly against your DB - only via objects provided by you. *"So is it really best practice to use `Int16` in this scenario?"* - all numeric types in Ora and .Net don't match. ODP will return `Int64` where SqlClient returns `Int32`. You need to use `Convert.ToInt32` over what `IDataReader` Returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a check constraint to validate the `number(5,0)` column fits in the bounds of `int16`.

```
 alter table your_table add constraint your_col_int16_ck 
     check ( your_col >= -32768 and your_col <= 32767 )
```

This will validate the data coming from your app and protect you from people issuing DML against your table through other vectors too.